# Error deploying Laravel application to Elastic Beanstalk with AWS S3 file upload

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am uploading files to AWS S3 from Laravel using the Flysystem package. I deploy the application on Elastic Beanstalk. But the deployment is getting failed and producing the following error:

> [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install composer dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/tests/Credentials/testlink: no such file or directory

The files to S3 are getting uploaded properly with this package in local environment. Only facing the issue while deploying the Laravel application using Elastic Beanstalk.

I installed the package using this statement:

> composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "~1.0"

My Laravel project version is 8.x